# left-edge vertical alignment in gb4e

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

I use gb4e for formatting linguistic examples. I came to an example in which I want to show that one translation is correct and another reading is not allowed. I'd like to indicate that the second translation is bad by placing a raised asterisk before it. gb4e provides a way to align the left-edge vertically when an asterisk is placed in front of the first line (to indicate that the example itself is ungrammatical). Is there a way to align the left-edge when an asterisk is put on the second translation line (the \glt line)?

A MWE is as follows (I'm using xelatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll  bites dog cat\\
    verb dd  cc\\
 \glt   `The dog bites the cat.'\\
 $^*$`The cat bites the dog.'
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to roll your own: Latex provides `\llap`, which will do just what you're after.

```
\glt     `The dog bites the cat.'\\
  \llap{$^*$}`The cat bites the dog.'
```

The contents of `\llap{}` are typeset in a box aligned to the left of the insertion point. The box is assigned nominal zero width, keeping the insertion point unchanged.

Note that the contents of `\llap{}` are effectively plastered *over* whatever is on its left. In your case this is always whitespace, but if you use it at the very start of an example, i.e., immediately after `\ex`, it may overstrike the example number if there is not enough space.

Comment: This is even better! Works great. Thank you.

Comment: Better using `\makebox[0pt][r]{$^*$}`; but why not simply `\makebox[0pt][r]{*}`?

Comment: @egreg, I wrote `$^*$` because that's what the OP wanted; I use a simple `*` myself. What problem does `\llap` have, that you solve by using `\makebox`?

Comment: @alexis Try `<blank line>\llap{$^*$}Here is the problem.`

Comment: Ah, ok. Not a problem in this use case, but I'll edit asap to mention vertical mode.